# Как подключиться к экземпляру SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Такая проблема, начал изучать по документации MS - SQL Server, решил я к Ядру СУБД подключиться, сделал как написано было: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/lesson-1-connecting-to-the-database-engine

Ну то есть зарегал я себе сервак с именем Imperator2018, но до этого я работал в дефолтном сервере (localdb). В итоге я не пойму в чем проблема, вроде зарегал сервак, но подключаться не получается.

Может что-то не так делаю???

На 1 скриншоте ошибка вылезла, когда нажал "проверить".
На 2 скрине сервер, к которому всегда подключался.
На 3 скрине подключение к Imperator2018

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема одна (не получилось установить соединение с сервером), причины могут быть разными. Указанное имя Imperator2018 - резолвится в правильный сервер, сервер доступен по сети (пинг по этому имени проходит)? Инстанс MSSQL на Imperator2018 - дефолтный (не нужно ли добавить имя инстанса, например `Imperator2018\MyTestDB`)? Сервис MSSQL запущен на хосте Imperator2018? Разрешены ли упомянутые в сообщении на скриншоте Named Pipes соединения для MSSQL на Imperator2018?

Comment: Я просто делал все как в документации, но на шаге задачи- регистрация лок сервера вышла ошибка, я решил просто зарегать новый сервер.

Comment: Imperator2018 - это ваш локальный компьютер? то есть и MSSQL и SQL management studio запущены на одном хосте? По инструкции вроде должно быть так, и вы должны быть администратором на этом хосте. Проверьте пункт `Подтверждение того, что компонент ядра СУБД запущен` из статьи: на скриншоте нет зеленой точки со стрелкой, зато есть синяя со знаком вопроса. Это может означать, что WMI сервис не запущен на компьютере (точнее - что SSMS, используя WMI запрос, не может получить сведения, запущен ли MSSQL инстанс). Проверьте, запущен ли сервис WMI в оснастке Services(`services.msc`)